# How does Outlook get the address lists from Exchange Server?

Tags: c#, active-directory, outlook, exchangewebservices

We try to get the same Address Lists that Outlook shows.

As of now, we get the Address Lists using an expanded version of Henning Krause's [Searching the Global Address List](http://www.infinitec.de/post/2011/10/25/Searching-the-Global-Address-List-C-Edition.aspx). This worked well during the last year, with on-premise deployments.

Now if you use cloud services, this does not work. The local AD and the cloud AD are synchronized somehow, and they are not trusted. The local AD does contain Exchange schema (the users have msExch... properties set), but it doesn't contain Address Lists, or at least not where the script would like it to be.

However, using some builtin magic, Outlook can get the Address Lists, while the script cannot.

So, how does Outlook get the Address Lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook uses the same API as for the stores - RPC over HTTP or MAPI over HTTP to connect to the AB services on the remote computer. It does not use AD API.

Is using Outlook Object Model an option?

Comment: I don't think so. Our program has to run on servers that don't have Outlook installed. If I understand documentation correctly, Outlook has to be installed on every computer where we want to use Outlook Object Model.

Comment: EWS is available, but Exchange 2010 compatibility is required - SP2 at least.

Comment: EWS was introduced in Exchange 2007.

Comment: But not all features of EWS are available with 2007 or 2010. ResolveName  is available starting 2013.

Comment: I can only think of doing RPC-over-HTTP - not for the faint-hearted, even if the format is documented...